# Callback functions in python

Tags: python

```py
def chunks_process(chunks, pos, folder_name, whole_text):
    r = sr.Recognizer()
    for i in range(pos, len(chunks)):
        chunk_filename = os.path.join(folder_name, f"chunk{i}.wav")
        chunks[i].export(chunk_filename, format="wav")
        with sr.AudioFile(chunk_filename) as source:
            audio_listened = r.record(source)
            try:
                text = r.recognize_google(audio_listened, language='vi-VN')
            except:
                chunks_process(chunks, i, folder_name, whole_text)
            else:
                text = f"{text.capitalize()}. "
                print(chunk_filename, ":", text)
                whole_text += text
        
    return whole_text
```

I want to callback **chunks_process**() funtion whenever **r.recognize_google()** api call fail at the specific position.

I have a problem that it repeat the **for loop** after finishing the end index of an array(chunks).

I don't know how to resolve this problem.

Comment: This had me confused for a while because of the phrase "callback function". The phrase *usually* refers to a function that is passed as a parameter to another function, and which is called from that function to solve some sub-task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because you do not stop when getting back from a recursive call. The `i` of the caller is not updated by the `i` of the recursive execution.

The solution is to *return* immediately when you get back from recursion, because at that point all is processed. So add `return` here:

```
     return chunks_process(chunks, i, folder_name, whole_text)
```

As a side note: it seems that with the recursive call you want to *retry* an operation. I would not use recursion for that, but just write an additional loop that keeps iterating as long as a retry is needed.